# trying to make dataframe from multiple csv files - UnicodeEncodeError: 'mbcs' codec can't encode characters in position 0--1: invalid character

Tags: python, pandas

i am trying to import multiple csv files from a folder as one big data frame.

im getting 
"UnicodeEncodeError: 'mbcs' codec can't encode characters in position 0--1: invalid character"

i tried to use global

```
 all_files = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")
 li = []

  for filename in all_files:
      df = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=None, header=0)
      li.append(df)

  UnicodeEncodeError: 'mbcs' codec can't encode characters in position 0- 
  -1: invalid character
```

Comment: Try ‘encoding=Latin-1’

Comment: i tried, no success :(